# How do I use .htaccess to always redirect from HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: .htaccess, http

There's a few similar questions which I tried to work out the answer from, but so far I have been unsuccessful. Please advise how I can always redirect http to https (and also remove *www.* from the hostname in the process). Also a side note, it would be nice to do this inside the main Apache conf rather than `.htaccess` - but I imagine this will not apply to most people.

- [.htaccess redirect www to non-www with SSL/HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478173/htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-ssl-https)
- [Redirect subdomain request to subdirectory + https (using .htaccess)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545097/redirect-subdomain-request-to-subdirectory-https-using-htaccess)
- [htaccess redirect for non-www both http and https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015159/htaccess-redirect-for-non-www-both-http-and-https)

#### Update:

I've added this snippet to a `VirtualHost` section:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

... but it has no effect when I access `http://www.domain` (it should redirect to `https://domain`)

#### Update 2:

It had no effect because I did not use `RewriteEngine on` - so it works now:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What's wrong with all the other answers? How have you been unsuccessful? Also, there's pretty much no difference between doing this in .htaccess and your main Apache config file.

Comment: When using in the main conf file: `Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Comment: What does your server configuration look like?

Comment: Snippet from a `VirtualHost` section: http://pastebin.com/Zp5Qc6FA

Comment: You might want to update your question with the details you've put in your comment about the error you're getting.

Comment: @Nick Bolton: The error message says “Invalid command 'RewriteEngine' …”. You should show us in what context you use that directive.

Comment: Oops, rookie mistake - the mod wasn't loaded, but it is now (thanks Andrew Aylett). So on to my question, how do I do what I want to do?

Comment: I think this would be more at home on Server Fault than SO.

Comment: jmtd: hmm, yes you're right. Hopefully the mods will migrate this. There are also a number of other Apache conf questions on SO.

Comment: @Nick Bolton: As you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use `mod_rewrite`, you can achieve it simply with `mod_alias`:

```
Redirect permanent / https://other-site
```

Where 'other-site' is the hostname you want to redirect to, ommitting the www. prefix that you do not want.

Comment: Ok, this worked, but only for the `VirtualHost *:80`, so in *:443 I will try to use a snippet similar to my answer.

Answer (score 18):

There are so many solutions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://yourdomain/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I like this answer the best, because it's very concise on https. To extend it to work with any domain...   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]  RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a load balancer you'll need to use a different conditional. This works for AWS ELB:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule (.*) https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I can confirm that this also works on the load balancer for WPEngine.com

Answer (score 4):

two solutions . add either of them to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCondition %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, it sounds like you're not including mod_rewrite:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: Ah, yep, you're right. Ok, now on to the question...